# Prove by induction that $3^n > n^2$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, induction

> Prove by induction that $3^n > n^2$

I tried to prove this but I finally got to a point from where I could not proceed any further. 
I tested this and this relation seems to be true for all $n \in \mathbb N$. 
 
(1) The first step: $3^1 > 1^2$, the inequality holds. 
(2) I assume that this relation inequality holds for all natural numbers smaller than or equal to some $k$, and so $3^k > k^2$ 
(3) The inductive step: 
$$3^{k+1} =3 \cdot 3^k > 3k^2 =k^2 + k^2 + k^2$$
This would be great if I could show that $k^2+k^2 > 2k +1$ for all natural numbers. Unfortunately, this is simply not the case for $n=1$, because $2 < 3$. And so my idea does not work. Is there an alternative way to tackle this problem?

Comment: For $n=1$ you have shown it already, see $(1)$.

Comment: The base case should be $n=2$.  Then, your analysis works for $k\ge 2$.  And incidentally, $3^1>1^2$ also.  So, the inequality is correct for all natural numbers.

Comment: Adding  second base case $n=2$  is perfectly acceptable.  However you do not need to, as $3*3^k$ is *strictly* greater than $3*k^2$ you *don't* have to show that $k^2 + k^2$ is strictly greater than $2k+1$; only that it is greater or equal to $2k+1$.

Comment: Oh, wait.   $k^2 + k^2 < 2k + 1$ if $k = 1$.  ... oh well,  A second base case is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This would be great if I could show that $k^2+k^2>2k+1$ for all natural numbers."

That would be great.  But as $3^{k+1} > k^2+ k^2+k^2$.  You actually only have to show that $k^2 + k^2 \ge 2k + 1$ for all natural numbers.  (i.e. $3^{k+1} = 3*3^{k} > 3*k^2 = k^2 + k^2 + k^2 \ge k^2 + 2k + 1$)

Which you've certainly demonstrated you are capable of doing.

=====

BTW.  There is nothing wrong when you hit a localized snag with, breaking into specific and general cases.  Example:

"If $k \ge 2$ then $k^2 + k^2 > 2k + 1$.  And if $k = 1$ then $k+1 = 2$ and $3^2 > 2^2$."

Absolutely nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Hmmph... actually I was wrong.  $k^2 + k^2 \not \ge 2k+1$ for $k=1$.  (D'oh!) ... so second base case is fine.